# PopupWindow Dismiss function works on one window but not another

Tags: c#, android, mobile

I currently have 2 `PopupWindow`, one dismisses straight away upon `Button` press.

```
    private async void ClosePopupWindow(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        _popUpReceiptWindow.Dismiss();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(Intent.Flags);
        Finish();
    }
```

Due to the nature of that `PopupWindow` it closes and then switches to a different `Activity`.

The window that does not dismiss correctly is this line of code.

```
    private void CloseEftWindow(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        _popupEftWindow.Dismiss();
    }
```

Here is the initialisation of the window that doesn't close properly:

```
    private void EftButton_OnTouchedAsync(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        _eftButton.Touch -= EftButton_OnTouchedAsync;

        var popupEftView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CreditCardPopupWindow, null);

        _creditCardState = EftType.EftCardInserted;
        _popUpCashbackButton = popupEftView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.popupCreditCardCashBackButton);
        _popupEFTCancelButton = popupEftView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.popupCreditCardCancel);

        _popupEftWindow = new PopupWindow(popupEftView, _subTotalLayout.Width, 500, true);
        _popupEftWindow.ShowAtLocation(_subTotalLayout, GravityFlags.Bottom, 0, 0);
        _popupEFTCancelButton.Touch += CloseEftWindow;

        SubscribeCreditCardElements(popupEftView);

        CreditCardStateTranstion(EftType.EftCardInserted);

        _popUpCashbackButton.Touch += CashbackButtonSelected;

        _eftButton.Touch += EftButton_OnTouchedAsync;

    }
```

And here is the initialisation that does close properly:

```
    private void UnderZeroBalanceReached()
    {
        View popUpView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PopupView, null);


        if (_totalAmount <= 0)
        {
            _popUpOkButton = popUpView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.popupReceiptYesButton);
            _popUpReceiptWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, _subTotalLayout.Width, 500, true);
            _popUpReceiptWindow.ShowAtLocation(_subTotalLayout, GravityFlags.Bottom, 0, 0);
            _popUpOkButton.Touch += ClosePopupWindow;

            DisableRightSidePaneButtons();
        }

    }
```

Is anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong? I've used breakpoints on the dismissal of the eft popupwindow but cant see why it's not actually shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why but within the Method DisableRightSidePaneButtons(), there are lines of code that disable elements such as Buttons and TextViews and make them invisible. The PopUpWindow would only be dismissed if the button that initiates it had been disabled and been made invisible.